# No load Map Android - Google Maps V2

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors, google-maps-api-2

I have an problem with creating of an aplication of Google Maps V2 Android. Sorry about my English. This is my problem:

```
01-17 15:24:55.844: E/AndroidRuntime(26859): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  
Expected 6171000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

---

**MainActivity:**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap googleMap;    
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;    
    int locationCount = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available           

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);           

            // Opening the sharedPreferences object
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);

            // Getting number of locations already stored
            locationCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("locationCount", 0);


            // Getting stored zoom level if exists else return 0
            String zoom = sharedPreferences.getString("zoom", "0");

            // If locations are already saved
            if(locationCount!=0){           

                String lat = "";
                String lng = "";

                // Iterating through all the locations stored
                for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++){

                    // Getting the latitude of the i-th location
                    lat = sharedPreferences.getString("lat"+i,"0");

                    // Getting the longitude of the i-th location
                    lng = sharedPreferences.getString("lng"+i,"0");

                    // Drawing marker on the map
                    drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng)));                   
                }

                // Moving CameraPosition to last clicked position
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng))));

                // Setting the zoom level in the map on last position  is clicked
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(Float.parseFloat(zoom)));                            
            }

        }        

        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {      
                locationCount++;

                // Drawing marker on the map
                drawMarker(point);

                /** Opening the editor object to write data to sharedPreferences */
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();         

                // Storing the latitude for the i-th location
                editor.putString("lat"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(point.latitude));

                // Storing the longitude for the i-th location
                editor.putString("lng"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(point.longitude));

                // Storing the count of locations or marker count
                editor.putInt("locationCount", locationCount);              

                /** Storing the zoom level to the shared preferences */
                editor.putString("zoom", Float.toString(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom));               

                /** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
                editor.commit();            

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Marker is added to the Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  

            }
        }); 


        googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {              
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

                // Removing the marker and circle from the Google Map
                googleMap.clear();

                // Opening the editor object to delete data from sharedPreferences
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                // Clearing the editor
                editor.clear();

                // Committing the changes
                editor.commit();

                // Setting locationCount to zero
                locationCount=0;

            }
        });           


    }

    private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
        // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();                  

        // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
        markerOptions.position(point);

        // Adding marker on the Google Map
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);         
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkerpreferences"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
          android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkerpreferences.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkerpreferences.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>   

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkerpreferences.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBDEKZK3rQiiqC6q1ZXCuDvL5iC00-EOnY" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**Properties:**

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you start from reading and understanding stacktrace you pasted

Comment: If no answer , why mess ?

Comment: If you cannot understand self explanatory error message, then perhaps programming is not your destiny.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, I'm not asking to identify the error , I am asking for a solution to it . if not noticed , I am beginner.

Comment: I am giving you the solution. **READ THE ERROR MESSAGE**!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have read the exception you pasted here and do what it tells:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  
Expected 6171000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element: 
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

so simply edit your Manifest and add

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

to it.

Comment: It is difficult to help ? It hurt ? THANKS!

Comment: it's not the matter of helping. It's matter of your laziness. You got error message that tells you exactly what to do to fix the problem, yet you **fail** to read it with basic understanding. Understanding this **is** difficult. It's even worse when one realizes this is just basic error. What would you do when something more complex occur?

Comment: Marcin Orlowski, You do not understand. My problem was in English. I'm good in the code and logic. I solved all problems. What about the problem: what happens is that I copied this code and has come in error. I had to turn around to solve. Thanks for your help.